# Php create table from dynamic td tr

Tags: php, html

I have tried to create a table from the dynamic array with dynamic row cell.

When row found in the array it will add `<tr>` tag in first and till the next `row` found in the array. I want like when row found `tr` tag will start with `td` tag inside until next row found in array And then again same `tr` tag will start until the next row found in the array.

**Here is the example of an array**

```
$cars = array (
      array(
          'table_body_element'=>'row',
          'cell_text'=>'',
      ),
      array(
          'table_body_element'=>'cell',
          'cell_text'=>'Column 1',
      ),
      array(
          'table_body_element'=>'cell',
          'cell_text'=>'Column 2',
      ),
      array(
          'table_body_element'=>'cell',
          'cell_text'=>'Column 3',
      ),
      array(
          'table_body_element'=>'row',
          'cell_text'=>'',
      ),
      array(
          'table_body_element'=>'cell',
          'cell_text'=>'Column 11',
      ),
      array(
          'table_body_element'=>'cell',
          'cell_text'=>'Column 22',
      ),
      array(
          'table_body_element'=>'row',
          'cell_text'=>'',
      ),
    );
```

*And I have tried to check is it row tag or not and add tr tag on it.*

**Here is my foreach loop.**

```
echo '<table><thead><tr>';
foreach ($cars as $item){
    echo '<td>'.$item[ 'cell_text' ].'</td>';
    if( $item[ 'table_body_element' ] == 'row' ){
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
}
echo '</tr></tbody></table>';
```

**Output**

[image]

The output showing like this now. With fast empty tr div without td
 content and last another tr div printing without content. and I want to remove this only content tr tag and td need to be print in the result.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have the foreach inside the table, having  at the end of the foreach is not good in my opinion. Try this:

```
echo '<table><tbody>';
foreach ($cars as $item){
    echo '<tr><td>'.$item[ 'cell_text' ].'</td>';
    if( $item[ 'table_body_element' ] == 'row' ){
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Comment: This is printed in all td tag with tr. also printing blank tr tag in the first time in table. I want like when row found tr tag will start with td until next row found in array

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are always putting out the cell text first, even for `row`s, and you always open the next line when you get a new row in...

```
echo '</tr><tr>';
```

at least you close it, but it's difficult (without maintaining various flags) to decide when to output the start tag.

Alternative, this builds up each row and then uses `implode()` the the `$rows` array to add the `<tr></tr>` tags round them...

```
echo '<table><thead>';
$rows = [];
$row = '';
foreach ( $cars as $car )   {
    if ( $car['table_body_element'] == 'row' ) {
        if ( !empty($row) ) {
            $rows [] = $row;
            $row = '';
        }
    }
    else    {
        $row .= '<td>'.$car[ 'cell_text' ].'</td>';
    }
}
echo '<tr>'.implode( '</tr><tr>', $rows ).'</tr>';
echo '</tbody></table>';
```